# jquery selector - Select value not inside another nested tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to select the value of a tag which is not inside another nested tag?

For example in the following code I want to get ' Text I want to select' from $('#example').

```
<td id="example">
    <a> Text I don't want to select</a>
    <span> Other text I don't want to select</span>
    Text I want to select
    <anyOtherTag> Other text I don't want to select</anyOtherTag>
</td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a helper function for this. Here is a great thread on the issue (How do I select text nodes w/ jQuery). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) down to text node types (`nodeType == 3`), like this:

```
var text = $("#example").contents().filter(function() { 
              return this.nodeType == 3; 
           }).text();
alert($.trim(text));
```

[You can try it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JsUTh/).  since `.text()` gets all text nodes, including the other whitespace, you probably want to [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) (since IE<9 doesn't have [`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)) the result like I have above.

Comment: Thanks good Idea. The only problem is that I don't get it working in my real example. Indeed my table is used with jquery plugin datatables and jeditable so when the user clicks on a table I want to get that information. I've logged my variables and I'm getting with $(this) the correct td, but when I do $(this).contents() it is empty. May it be because I'm using datatables plugin?

Comment: @Javi - it all depends on your context, try a `console.log(this)` and see where you are when it happens